# Connecting to Snowflake via SSO for RStudio

Tags: r, azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am currently trying to connect to Snowflake via Azure AD SSO. What I would like is for the browser window to pop up so that I can put in my credentials to log me into Snowflake.
This is the code that I am currently using:

```
connection <- DBI::dbConnect(
  drv = odbc::odbc(),
  dsn = "snowflake",
  server = "XXXXXXXXXXX.snowflakecomputing.com",
  Trusted_Connection = "True",
  authenticator = "externalbrowser"
)
```

A browser window does pop up, but it only has this message:

```
Your identity was confirmed and propagated to Snowflake ODBC driver. You can close this window now and go back where you started from.
```

And in my R console it says this:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 28000: The user you were trying to authenticate as differs from the user currently logged in at the IDP.
```

Where am I going wrong and how do I do this? :(

Comment: Are you able using the same browser to connect to the Snowflake UI?

Comment: What seems to be happening is that the the browser is taking the session for some other user which is logged in from the browser (for AAD). But, since that user is not present in Snowflake, it is failing to connect.
Try to close all the browser sessions and then test this.

Comment: @Sergiu Yes I am.

Comment: Try adding the user to the connection string and it should work.

Comment: @Sergiu hmm if I'm trying to use Azure AD SSO, would I put my email for the 'user'? I've just tried it, and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In your **connection** you can add **UID="username"**, but I haven't tested so not sure if it will be picked up for the external authentication.

Answer (score 0):

[ODBC required connection parameters](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html#required-connection-parameters) include the user id for the connection. As @Sergiu suggested, add the user information into the connection parameters. The user would be either yourself or whatever service account you may be using in RStudio.